# Pandas convert year column to date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing years:

```
col1 col2 ... year ... coln
 -    -   ... 2020 ...  -
 -    -   ... 2021 ...  -
 -    -   ... 2022 ...  -
```

I want to convert this to date by mapping year to 1st date of that year, like:

```
col1 col2 ... year       ... coln
 -    -   ... 2020-01-01 ...  -
 -    -   ... 2021-01-01 ...  -
 -    -   ... 2022-01-01 ...  -
```

I tried this:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

But it gives me this error:

> ValueError: time data '2020' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I always go check https://strftime.org/ for a quick reference on date formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%Y` for match year in format `YYYY`, but I think this parameter shoud be omitted:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')
```

---

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype('str') + "-01-01"
print(df)
```